# How do I remove an existing claim from a ClaimsPrincipal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, wif, claims-based-identity

I am making a developer tool for impersonating `Roles` for an intranet site to allow developers to quickly act as any `Role` as needed.  Roles defined are `Developer, Team Lead, Team Member, Engineering, Marketing, Guest` and a tool on the web page makes a call to a Web Api to add or remove the `Claim`... well I can add but can't seem to find out where the `.RemoveClaim(claim)` or `.TryRemoveClaim(claim)` can be accessed to get this working.  Do I have to create a custom claims manager to get this functionality or am I missing something?

I have been looking at [System.Security.Claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and almost everything else seems to work very straightforward and there is no reference as to needing extensive work to do what I need.

I am using VS 2013/Web Api2 with .NET 4.5.1.

The website side just uses a simple ajax call to `PUT` and `DELETE` functionality till I get this to work the way I want.  From the Controller, my cs code is as:

```
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string role)
    {
        if (FindClaim(role) != null) return;

        var user = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (user == null) return;

        var claimId = new ClaimsIdentity();
        claimId.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        user.AddIdentity(claimId);
    }

    // DELETE api/devroleadjuster/5
    public void Delete(int id, [FromBody]string role)
    {
        var claim = FindClaim(role);
        if (claim == null) return;

        var user = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (user == null)  return;

        // Why can't I do this????
        user.RemoveClaim(claim);
    }

    private Claim FindClaim(string role)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
            var claim = (from c in user.Claims
                         where c.Value == role
                         select c).Single();
            return claim;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The `Put` works just fine, the problem is with the `Delete` portion of my code... I want to use the `user.RemoveClaim(claim);` code or something like it... I can't see why I can't according to MSDN, and I can't find any example code for removing a claim.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should use identity to add or remove a claim. Try this to add a claim.

```
var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "somenewrole"));
```

To remove a claim,

```
var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var claim = (from c in user.Claims
                         where c.Value == "somenewrole"
                         select c).Single();
identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
```

BTW, it is better to use `User` from your controller instead of `HttpContext.Current.User`.

Comment: Yikes, very obvious now that you pointed it out... sometimes I get too close to the problem to think.  @Badri is there a reason why for the `HttpContext.Current.User` not to be used?  Its what the examples showed so if there is reason to be wary I would like to know.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `HttpContext` tightly-couples you to web hosting. Better to use the abstraction available in the form of `User` property. Check this link out - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1294, specifically the reply from David Matson (Search for davidmatson wrote Sep 13, 2013 at 9:18 PM).

Comment: I get an error when trying to remove a claim using Identity: `The Claim 'time_zone_string: Mountain Standard Time' was not able to be removed.  It is either not part of this Identity or it is a claim that is owned by the Principal that contains this Identity. For example, the Principal will own the claim when creating a GenericPrincipal with roles. The roles will be exposed through the Identity that is passed in the constructor, but not actually owned by the Identity.  Similar logic exists for a RolePrincipal.`

Comment: @Badri . Do you know how to get this to persist between pages loads?  Mine keeps reverting back to what it was before the change.

Comment: The Claim 'time_zone_string: Mountain Standard Time' was not able to be removed. It is either not part of this Identity or it is a claim that is owned by the Principal that contains this Identity. For example, the Principal will own the claim when creating a GenericPrincipal with roles. This may be misleading - for me the problem was a missing claim!

Answer (score 10):

Something else that is important to add is to make sure you do not try to iterate over the collection of claims and remove items.  I just stumbled upon buggy code written by someone else, and at first I didn't see the problem until I stepped through it.

The buggy code was:

```
        foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
        {
            var name = claim.Type;
            if (!name.Equals("UserAccountId") && !name.Equals("Email") && !name.Equals("TenantIds"))
            {
                identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
            }
        }
```

The result was that claims were inconsistently removed from the list.  The simple solution to the problem is to iterate over a list of claims and not the claims themselves, and remove them that way:

```
        var claimNameList = identity.Claims.Select(x => x.Type).ToList();

        foreach (var name in claimNameList)
        {
            if (!name.Equals("UserAccountId") && !name.Equals("Email") && !name.Equals("TenantIds"))
            {
                var claim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == name);
                if (claim != null)
                    identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
            }
        }
```

It's never a good idea to iterate over a collection and add or remove items.  You will see sporadic errors and different results depending on the situation, and in some circumstances, such as iterating over items in HttpContext.Current.Items, you will see sporadic errors about the collection being modified.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me without getting the "claim X was not able to be removed" error:

```
ClaimsPrincipal currentPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
foreach (var identity in currentPrincipal.Identities)
{
    Claim claim = identity.FindFirst(x => x.Value == role);
    if (claim != null)
    {
        identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Find the user then delete it.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
var claim =  _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user).Result.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == claimType);
var result =await _userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user, claim);
```

Comment: GetClaimsAsync Gets claims in DB, not identity Claims