# How to update a claim in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using OWIN authentication for my MVC5 project.
This is my `SignInAsync`

```
 private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            var AccountNo = "101";
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, AccountNo));
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent, RedirectUri="Account/Index"}, identity);
        }
```

As you can see, i added `AccountNo` into the Claims list.

Now,  how can I update this Claim at some point in my application? So far, i have this:

```
 public string AccountNo
        {

            get
            {
                var CP = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
                var Account= CP.Claims.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == ClaimTypes.UserData);
                return Account.Value;
            }
            set
            {
                var CP = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
                var AccountNo= CP.Claims.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == ClaimTypes.UserData).Value;
                CP.RemoveClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData,AccountNo));
                CP.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, value));
            }

        }
```

when i try to remove the claim, I get this exception:

> The Claim
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/userdata:
> 101' was not able to be removed.  It is either not part of this
> Identity or it is a claim that is owned by the Principal that contains
> this Identity. For example, the Principal will own the claim when
> creating a GenericPrincipal with roles. The roles will be exposed
> through the Identity that is passed in the constructor, but not
> actually owned by the Identity.  Similar logic exists for a
> RolePrincipal.

How does one remove and update the Claim?

Comment: If you are storing User Info in a Claim and you want to update the Claim, once User Info has changed, you can call: `SignInManager.SignInAsync` to refresh the value of the Claim. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663462/invalidate-claimsprincipal-after-it-has-been-modified?noredirect=1#comment96151754_54663462)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

I created a Extension method to Add/Update/Read Claims based on a given ClaimsIdentity

```
namespace Foobar.Common.Extensions
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void AddUpdateClaim(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, string key, string value)
        {
            var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity == null)
                return;

            // check for existing claim and remove it
            var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst(key);
            if (existingClaim != null)
                identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);

            // add new claim
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(key, value));
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
        }

        public static string GetClaimValue(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, string key)
        {
            var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity == null)
                return null;

            var claim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == key);

            // ?. prevents a exception if claim is null.
            return claim?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

and then to use it

```
using Foobar.Common.Extensions;

namespace Foobar.Web.Main.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // add/updating claims
            User.AddUpdateClaim("key1", "value1");
            User.AddUpdateClaim("key2", "value2");
            User.AddUpdateClaim("key3", "value3");
        }

        public ActionResult Details()
        {
            // reading a claim
            var key2 = User.GetClaimValue("key2");          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally.  I had another solution to this and it seemed to be working... mostly.  But ultimately switched to this method since it seems to work always.  Thank you!

Comment: Anybody has the same solution for Asp.Net One Core?

Comment: This appears only working for the current application.  I would like to update the cookie issued by SSO server so other apps can access them too.  Any idea how?  Thanks

Comment: @Whoever As the cookie is signed by the SSO server to show that it hasn't been tampered with (and thus can be trusted), I would be surprised if there was any way to achieve this as it would be tampering.

Comment: @Mog0 There's an illusion that this might work when applications are on the same domain, like during local debug.  So you are right, it cain't be done.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277702/identityserver3-cant-update-cookie-when-apps-are-on-different-machine/39291127#39291127

Comment: var claim = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == key); return claim.Value;should be var claim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == key); return claim?.Value;

Comment: @liuhongbo is right. `GetClaimValue` should `return null` if `claim == null` when using `FirstOrDefault`. Thanks for this though, it helped me!

Comment: Nicely picked up @liuhongbo and I've made changes accordingly

Comment: Thanks for this. Though not sure why you use the FindFirst method in AddOrUpdate(), but then manually compare when in GetClaimValue(). 
Really GetClaimValue() could just consist of `return (currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)?.FindFirst(key)?.Value;`. And can be even cleaner if you write it as an expression-bodied function.

Comment: Looking at the constructor of AuthenticationResponseGrant, it also accepts a instance of ClaimsIdentity instead of ClaimsPrincipal. Any difference in using that? Not a big difference, but would save creating a new object.

Comment: How do you do this with .net core 2.2? The authentication property is deprecated.

Comment: I had a problem that the claims for the current request was not updated, but found this: https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/issues/51 so that the current request gets updates.

Comment: Hello, I have a custom user store, so that I implemented IUserClaimStore in it. when I call `identity.AddClaim(new Claim(key, value));` from your code, the method `AddClaimAsync(T user, Claim claim)` of the user store is not called. Is there something extra I need to do?

Comment: it didn't worked

Answer (score 62):

You can create a new `ClaimsIdentity` and then do the claims update with such.

```
set {
    // get context of the authentication manager
    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

    // create a new identity from the old one
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);

    // update claim value
    identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("AccountNo"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccountNo", value));

    // tell the authentication manager to use this new identity
    authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = 
        new AuthenticationResponseGrant(
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }
        );
}
```

Comment: You can update the claim but still need to log the user out and in with the updated identity.

Comment: no it doesnt logout the user, we just updating the user's cookie

Comment: Remember that this updates identity only. If you want to store these claims and load them automatically upon request, you need the usermanager to remove and update them as well. Took me some time! :(

Comment: I would use a stored procedure to update the claim table directly.

Comment: What if I don't have cookies at all and use only accessToken? In my case claims are the same on the next request as before change. The only way to update claims I have is to logout user and ask him to login once again :-(

Comment: This appears only working for the current application.  I would like to update the cookie issued by SSO server so other apps can access them too.  Any idea how?  Thanks

Comment: I have replaced one claim value in MVC5 WEB API, it's replacing well. But when I am going to another `action` then it role backs to previous situation with the previous value. Why such happening?

Comment: This is due to not updating the cookies authenticated. This answer only updates the Identity which is at controller level. To get other parts of the app getting the updates, you need to refresh the sign in and renew the cookies. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53110508/1051256

Comment: Looking at the constructor of AuthenticationResponseGrant, it also accepts a instance of ClaimsIdentity instead of ClaimsPrincipal. Any difference in using that?  Not a big difference, but would save a cast.

Comment: `identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("AccountNo"));` will result in an InvalidOperationException if there is no claim of type "AccountNo" - in this situation there probably always is that claim, but in other situations you do it a bit more defensively with TryRemoveClaim e.g. `identity.TryRemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("AccountNo"));`

Answer (score 20):

Another (async) approach, using Identity's UserManager and SigninManager to reflect the change in the Identity cookie (and to optionally remove claims from db table AspNetUserClaims):

```
// Get User and a claims-based identity
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);

// Remove existing claim and replace with a new value
await UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user.Id, Identity.FindFirst("AccountNo"));
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("AccountNo", value));

// Re-Signin User to reflect the change in the Identity cookie
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

// [optional] remove claims from claims table dbo.AspNetUserClaims, if not needed
var userClaims = UserManager.GetClaims(user.Id);
if (userClaims.Any())
{
  foreach (var item in userClaims)
  {
    UserManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, item);
  }
}
```

Comment: The clue here, for me, was to do the `SignInAsync()` *after* setting up the Claims.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on removing the claims from the DB. Made me realize I needed to clean-up after myself.

Answer (score 16):

Using latest Asp.Net Identity with .net core 2.1, I'm being able to update user claims with the following logic.

1. Register a `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` so that every time `SignInManager` sings user in, the claims are created.

   ```
   services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimService>();
   ```
2. Implement a custom `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>` like below

   ```
   public class UserClaimService : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>
   {
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

       public UserClaimService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
       {
           _dbContext = dbContext;
       }

       public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
       {
           var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

           // Get user claims from DB using dbContext

           // Add claims
           ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("claimType", "some important claim value"));

           return principal;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Later in your application when you change something in the DB and would like to reflect this to your authenticated and signed in user, following lines achieves this:

   ```
   var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
   ```

This makes sure user can see up to date information without requiring login again. I put this just before returning the result in the controller so that when the operation finishes, everything securely refreshed.

Instead of editing existing claims and creating race conditions for secure cookie etc, you just sign user in silently and refresh the state :)

Comment: Thanks, faced the same issue and this solution works better for updating the claims  for a signed user.

Comment: Thanks! faced the same issue as well in net core 3.1

Comment: For me, I add just Step-3 lines and it's working fine for me. Thanks @Mahmut C

Answer (score 7):

I get that exception too and cleared things up like this

```
var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(identity.AuthenticationType, identity.NameClaimType, identity.RoleClaimType);
newIdentity.AddClaims(identity.Claims.Where(c => false == (c.Type == claim.Type && c.Value == claim.Value)));
// the claim has been removed, you can add it with a new value now if desired
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(identity.AuthenticationType);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, newIdentity);
```

Answer (score 5):

Compiled some answers from here into **re-usable ClaimsManager** class with my additions.

Claims got persisted, user cookie updated, sign in refreshed.

Please note that ApplicationUser can be substituted with IdentityUser if you didn't customize former. Also in my case it needs to have slightly different logic in Development environment, so you might want to remove IWebHostEnvironment dependency.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using YourMvcCoreProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace YourMvcCoreProject.Identity
{
    public class ClaimsManager
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        private readonly ClaimsPrincipalAccessor _currentPrincipalAccessor;

        public ClaimsManager(
            ClaimsPrincipalAccessor currentPrincipalAccessor,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _currentPrincipalAccessor = currentPrincipalAccessor;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _env = env;
        }

        /// <param name="refreshSignin">Sometimes (e.g. when adding multiple claims at once) it is desirable to refresh cookie only once, for the last one </param>
        public async Task AddUpdateClaim(string claimType, string claimValue, bool refreshSignin = true)
        {
            await AddClaim(
                _currentPrincipalAccessor.ClaimsPrincipal,
                claimType,
                claimValue, 
                async user =>
                {
                    await RemoveClaim(_currentPrincipalAccessor.ClaimsPrincipal, user, claimType);
                },
                refreshSignin);
        }

        public async Task AddClaim(string claimType, string claimValue, bool refreshSignin = true)
        {
            await AddClaim(_currentPrincipalAccessor.ClaimsPrincipal, claimType, claimValue, refreshSignin);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// At certain stages of user auth there is no user yet in context but there is one to work with in client code (e.g. calling from ClaimsTransformer)
        /// that's why we have principal as param
        /// </summary>
        public async Task AddClaim(ClaimsPrincipal principal, string claimType, string claimValue, bool refreshSignin = true)
        {
            await AddClaim(
                principal,
                claimType,
                claimValue, 
                async user =>
                {
                    // allow reassignment in dev
                    if (_env.IsDevelopment()) 
                        await RemoveClaim(principal, user, claimType);

                    if (GetClaim(principal, claimType) != null)
                        throw new ClaimCantBeReassignedException(claimType);                
                },
                refreshSignin);
        }

        public async Task RemoveClaims(IEnumerable<string> claimTypes, bool refreshSignin = true)
        {
            await RemoveClaims(_currentPrincipalAccessor.ClaimsPrincipal, claimTypes, refreshSignin);
        }

        public async Task RemoveClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal, IEnumerable<string> claimTypes, bool refreshSignin = true)
        {
            AssertAuthenticated(principal);
            foreach (var claimType in claimTypes)
            {
                await RemoveClaim(principal, claimType);
            }
            // reflect the change in the Identity cookie
            if (refreshSignin)
                await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal));
        }

        public async Task RemoveClaim(string claimType, bool refreshSignin = true)
        {
            await RemoveClaim(_currentPrincipalAccessor.ClaimsPrincipal, claimType, refreshSignin);
        }

        public async Task RemoveClaim(ClaimsPrincipal principal, string claimType, bool refreshSignin = true)
        {
            AssertAuthenticated(principal);
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
            await RemoveClaim(principal, user, claimType);
            // reflect the change in the Identity cookie
            if (refreshSignin)
                await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        }

        private async Task AddClaim(ClaimsPrincipal principal, string claimType, string claimValue, Func<ApplicationUser, Task> processExistingClaims, bool refreshSignin)
        {
            AssertAuthenticated(principal);
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
            await processExistingClaims(user);
            var claim = new Claim(claimType, claimValue);
            ClaimsIdentity(principal).AddClaim(claim);
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);
            // reflect the change in the Identity cookie
            if (refreshSignin)
                await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Due to bugs or as result of debug it can be more than one identity of the same type.
        /// The method removes all the claims of a given type.
        /// </summary>
        private async Task RemoveClaim(ClaimsPrincipal principal, ApplicationUser user, string claimType)
        {
            AssertAuthenticated(principal);
            var identity = ClaimsIdentity(principal);
            var claims = identity.FindAll(claimType).ToArray();
            if (claims.Length > 0)
            {
                await _userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(user, claims);
                foreach (var c in claims)
                {
                    identity.RemoveClaim(c);
                }
            }
        }

        private static Claim GetClaim(ClaimsPrincipal principal, string claimType)
        {
            return ClaimsIdentity(principal).FindFirst(claimType);    
        }    

        /// <summary>
        /// This kind of bugs has to be found during testing phase
        /// </summary>
        private static void AssertAuthenticated(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("User should be authenticated in order to update claims");
        }

        private static ClaimsIdentity ClaimsIdentity(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            return (ClaimsIdentity) principal.Identity;
        }
    }


    public class ClaimCantBeReassignedException : Exception
    {
        public ClaimCantBeReassignedException(string claimType) : base($"{claimType} can not be reassigned")
        {
        }
    }

public class ClaimsPrincipalAccessor
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ClaimsPrincipalAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal ClaimsPrincipal => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
}

// to register dependency put this into your Startup.cs and inject ClaimsManager into Controller constructor (or other class) the in same way as you do for other dependencies    
public class Startup
{
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ClaimsPrincipalAccessor>();
        services.AddTransient<ClaimsManager>();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

when I use MVC5, and add the claim here.

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(PATAUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, this.Role));

        return userIdentity;
    }
```

when I'm check the claim result in the SignInAsync function,i can't get the role value use anyway. But...

after this request finished, I can access Role in other action(anther request).

```
 var userWithClaims = (ClaimsPrincipal)User;
        Claim CRole = userWithClaims.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role);
```

so, i think maybe asynchronous cause the IEnumerable updated behind the process.

Answer (score 2):

You can update claims for the current user by implementing a `CookieAuthenticationEvents` class and overriding `ValidatePrincipal`. There you can remove the old claim, add the new one, and then replace the principal using `CookieValidatePrincipalContext.ReplacePrincipal`. This does not affect any claims stored in the database. This is using ASP.NET Core Identity 2.2.

```
public class MyCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    string newAccountNo = "102";

    public override Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        // first remove the old claim
        var claim = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData);
        if (claim != null)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).RemoveClaim(claim);
        }

        // add the new claim
        ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, newAccountNo));

        // replace the claims
        context.ReplacePrincipal(context.Principal);
        context.ShouldRenew = true;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You need to register the events class in `Startup.cs`:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<MyCookieAuthenticationEvents>();

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
    {
        o.EventsType = typeof(MyCookieAuthenticationEvents);
    });
}
```

You can inject services into the events class to access the new `AccountNo` value but as per the warning on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#react-to-back-end-changes) you should avoid doing anything too expensive:

> Warning
>
> The approach described here is triggered on every request. Validating
>   authentication cookies for all users on every request can result in a
>   large performance penalty for the app.

Comment: thanks, this worked great for me in asp.net core 3.1!

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate this question was about .NET 4/ OWIN, but to aid searchers looking for the .NET 5 or later equivalent, here's some sample code.

I'm sure you can improve it, but it's a working starter using the `UserManager` and `SignInManager` in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`.

```
// Get the user first first. 
var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
var givenNameClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Type == JwtClaimTypes.GivenName);

IdentityResult result = null;

if (givenNameClaim != null)
{
    result = await _userManager.ReplaceClaimAsync(user, givenNameClaim, new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "<newvalue>"));
}
else
{
    result = await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "<newvalue>"));
}

if (result.Errors.Any())
{
    // TODO: List errors here;
}
else
{
    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user); // refresh the login, so it takes effect immediately.
}
```

Comment: How to I get the UserManager first and the user for the first line?

Comment: That would be dependency injected into the controller or class. Maybe something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292582/accessing-usermanager-outside-accountcontroller) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a .net core 2.2 app and used the following solution:
in my statup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        ...
           services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
               {
                  ...
               })
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AdminDbContext>()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
               .AddSignInManager();
```

usage

```
  private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;


        public YourController(
                                    ...,
SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
           ...
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

 public async Task<IActionResult> YourMethod() // <-NOTE IT IS ASYNC
        {
                var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
                var claimToUse = ClaimsHelpers.CreateClaim(ClaimTypes.ActiveCompany, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cc));
                var claimToRemove = _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user).Result
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.ActiveCompany.ToString());
                if (claimToRemove != null)
                {
                    var result = _userManager.ReplaceClaimAsync(user, claimToRemove, claimToUse).Result;
                    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user); //<--- THIS
                }
                else ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for updating existing claims for me at the moment was:

```
//updating user data        
await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
```

Comment: This works, I finally give up the pieces of IUserStore, SignInManager, UserManager, ClaimsPrincipalAccessor, ClaimsManager ... really complicated things

Comment: it is not working for me, I didnt see new user claims in HttpContext.User.Claims after call SignInAsync. do you have an idea?

Comment: @Caner As it was with me. There are claims based on user data in the database. I updated them and then re-registered the user so that the app updates the claims on its own. You can also update claims manually, but then you have to update cookies, etc. also manually, but with this I have not figured out how to do it, and I can’t tell you.
P.s. sorry for google translate)

Answer (score 0):

To remove claim details from database we can use below code. Also, we need to sign in again to update the cookie values

```
 // create a new identity 
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);

            // Remove the existing claim value of current user from database
            if(identity.FindFirst("NameOfUser")!=null)
                await UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(applicationUser.Id, identity.FindFirst("NameOfUser"));

            // Update customized claim 
            await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(applicationUser.Id, new Claim("NameOfUser", applicationUser.Name));

            // the claim has been updates, We need to change the cookie value for getting the updated claim
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(identity.AuthenticationType);
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(Userprofile, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Cookies,Multiple Claims

```
public class ClaimsCookie
    {
        private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _user;
        private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
        public ClaimsCookie(ClaimsPrincipal user, HttpContext httpContext = null)
        {
            _user = user;
            _httpContext = httpContext;
        }

        public string GetValue(CookieName cookieName, KeyName keyName)
        {
            var principal = _user as ClaimsPrincipal;
            var cp = principal.Identities.First(i => i.AuthenticationType == ((CookieName)cookieName).ToString());
            return cp.FindFirst(((KeyName)keyName).ToString()).Value;
        }
        public async void SetValue(CookieName cookieName, KeyName[] keyName, string[] value)
        {
            if (keyName.Length != value.Length)
            {
                return;
            }
            var principal = _user as ClaimsPrincipal;
            var cp = principal.Identities.First(i => i.AuthenticationType == ((CookieName)cookieName).ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < keyName.Length; i++)
            {
                if (cp.FindFirst(((KeyName)keyName[i]).ToString()) != null)
                {
                    cp.RemoveClaim(cp.FindFirst(((KeyName)keyName[i]).ToString()));
                    cp.AddClaim(new Claim(((KeyName)keyName[i]).ToString(), value[i]));
                }

            }
            await _httpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieName.UserProfilCookie.ToString());
            await _httpContext.SignInAsync(CookieName.UserProfilCookie.ToString(), new ClaimsPrincipal(cp),
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = bool.Parse(cp.FindFirst(KeyName.IsPersistent.ToString()).Value),
                    AllowRefresh = true
                });
        }
        public enum CookieName
        {
            CompanyUserProfilCookie = 0, UserProfilCookie = 1, AdminPanelCookie = 2
        }
        public enum KeyName
        {
            Id, Name, Surname, Image, IsPersistent
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("userId"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("userId", userInfo?.id.ToString()));
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(HttpContext.User.Identity));
        }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread i know, but the requirements seem to have changed.

The below is working for me:

```
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(input.Email);

            var userClaim = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

            var userNameClaims = userClaim.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName).ToList();

            await _userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(user, userNameClaims);

            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.Forename));

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = input.RememberMe });
```

The sign out and in methods are essential, without the claims don't reflect the changes

Answer (score -1):

The extension method worked great for me with one exception that if the user logs out there old claim sets still existed so with a tiny modification as in passing usermanager through everything works great and you dont need to logout and login.
I cant answer directly as my reputation has been dissed :(

```
public static class ClaimExtensions
{
    public static void AddUpdateClaim(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal,    string key, string value, ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity == null)
            return;

        // check for existing claim and remove it
        var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst(key);
        if (existingClaim != null)
        {
            RemoveClaim(currentPrincipal, key, userManager);
        }

        // add new claim
        var claim = new Claim(key, value);
        identity.AddClaim(claim);
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
        //Persist to store
        userManager.AddClaim(identity.GetUserId(),claim);

    }

    public static void RemoveClaim(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, string key, ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity == null)
            return ;

        // check for existing claim and remove it
        var existingClaims = identity.FindAll(key);
        existingClaims.ForEach(c=> identity.RemoveClaim(c));

        //remove old claims from store
        var user = userManager.FindById(identity.GetUserId());
        var claims =  userManager.GetClaims(user.Id);
        claims.Where(x => x.Type == key).ToList().ForEach(c => userManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, c));

    }

    public static string GetClaimValue(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, string key)
    {
        var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity == null)
            return null;

        var claim = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == key);
        return claim.Value;
    }

    public static string GetAllClaims(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity == null)
            return null;

        var claims = userManager.GetClaims(identity.GetUserId());
        var userClaims = new StringBuilder();
        claims.ForEach(c => userClaims.AppendLine($"<li>{c.Type}, {c.Value}</li>"));
        return userClaims.ToString();
    }


}
```

Answer (score -4):

Here you go:

```
            var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
            var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var claim = (from c in user.Claims
                         where c.Type == ClaimTypes.UserData
                         select c).Single();
            identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
```

taken from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570743/how-do-i-remove-an-existing-claim-from-a-claimsprinciple)