# How to update a claim in ASP.NET Identity 3.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am working in a asp.net project and i need to update the value of a identity claim.

I read:

[How to update a claim in ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587414/how-to-update-a-claim-in-asp-net-identity)

I want to do something similar but in Identity 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this?

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);
identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("name"));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("name", "Jon"));

var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(
    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true
    });
```