# ASP.NET - How to manually remove/update a Claim that its type is DefaultRoleClaimType?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I want to remove a special **`Claim` that has `Role type`** by this code:

```
if (identity.HasClaim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, "MyPermissionName"))
{
    identity.RemoveClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType,
                                   "MyPermissionName",
                                   ClaimValueTypes.String));
}
```

But the framework giving me this error:

> The Claim
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role:
>   **MyPermissionName**' was not able to be removed.  It is either not
>   part of this Identity or it is a claim that is owned by the Principal
>   that contains this Identity. For example, the Principal will own the
>   claim when creating a GenericPrincipal with roles. The roles will be
>   exposed through the Identity that is passed in the constructor, but
>   not actually owned by the Identity.  Similar logic exists for a
>   RolePrincipal.

**How can I remove this type of claims** manually from claims of the identity of the user?

---

### Why I want to do it?

My project has **Roles + Permissions** (each role has several permission) and I initial the `Role type` `Claims` of `Identity` by **permission names instead of role names** in the `CustomClaimsIdentityFactory`.

It works well until I want to remove the `user` from a `role` by calling `RemoveFromRoleAsync` method. It *removes* the the user from the role in database but *dose not remove* the related role type claim automatically. I think the reason is using permission names instead of role names. Anyway I decided to remove the related role type claim manually and now I see the above error!

**What is your solution and suggestions?**

---

> **This question is unique (is not duplicate) because:** I can read/update/delete a claim normally but not about the
>   claims that their Key is `DefaultRoleClaimType` (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role), So this question is
>   not about deleting a normal claim that mentioned in other questions in SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a claim in ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587414/how-to-update-a-claim-in-asp-net-identity)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, No it is not about adding/updating or removing a normal claim! It is about removing a claim that has `DefaultRoleClaimType Key` (a Role Claim) and it seems the framework dose not allow to remove it. Then this is not duplicate.